# Authentication with Rest API

Tags: php, wordpress

I know that much of the Rest API has been integrated into core Wordpress, but what about authentication? I know basic authentication is supported but isn't meant for secure access since the login info is passed in plaintext. What about oAuth? Are there any tutorials on how to implement this with PHP? I am having trouble finding examples.
For my application, I am using the REST API to display content from my website through a plugin to be utilized on other users websites. Is there a way to display a login page with REST API so that users can login to my members area and access protected content without leaving their website?

Edited for clarity: I have a website with proprietary content that is restricted to my members. I am "reselling" access to my website so other providers can display my protected content directly from their own site. I am doing this by creating a plugin for other people to install on their site and they will place a shortcode. That shortcode will execute a script that uses Wordpress REST API to load content from my domain. How can users of this third party site login or register as a member to my site without leaving the 3rd party site?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you.. I use WooCommerce API. It has key and secret for connetion to api in general and use secure connection (https). And then I extended standard api with method for customer login. If you don't want to pass info in plaintext you can use for example `wp_set_auth_cookie($ID);` and do login by id without password (get id by login or email first with `get_user_by( 'email', $useremail )`)

Comment: Okay I will try to clarify: I have a website with proprietary content that is restricted to my members. I am "reselling" access to my website so other providers can display my protected content directly from their own site. I am doing this by creating a plugin for other people to install on their site and they will place a shortcode. That shortcode will execute a script that uses Wordpress REST API to load content from my domain. How can users of this third party site login or register as a member to my site without leaving the 3rd party site?

Comment: My opinion is that if you can "display content from my website through a plugin to be utilized on other users websites" the same way you can login/register users) Why do you want to "display a login page with REST API"? You need only login/email input field on the 3rd party site and when user send you email with API you can check if this user already registered or register as new (even without user password; if user is new - send email with random password) and after that pass you content to other site without redirect to your site.. Well something like this)

Comment: @questlooking Because access is restricted to paying members. I don't want strangers automatically getting memberships. If a user is trying to register they will need a 'discount code' which I will provide them in person. If they have this discount code and it matches our records, then their account is created. If they do not have a discount code then they are restricted from creating the account.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that helps you integrate OAuth in your WordPress installation: https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1

Check out also the [Authentication section of WP-API documentation](http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/). There are some paragraphs on OAuth.

Then you can code your login page using the theme development features of WordPress.

Comment: I've edited my original post. Is OAuth actually what I need for what I am trying to accomplish?